# mPDF Japanese font configuration

Tags: html, fonts, mpdf, cjk

I need to generate a PDF using mPDF and YuGothM.ttc font for a Japanese client. The page I need to export in PDF contains some text which in browser version (HTML) is rendered well, but in the PDF, the same text has some characters using a font and other characters some default font which is not approved by the client. I understand I have to define TTCfontID parameter in every font definition for .ttc files, but I just don't understand the meanings of those definitions and so how to properly configure fonts.

The script is used in a WordPress website using Polylang plugin for translations.

```
$defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    //'mode' => '+aCJK',
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => 'A3-L',
    'margin_left' => 5,
    'margin_right' => 5,
    'margin_top' => 5,
    'margin_bottom' => 5,

    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
        ASSETS_DIR ."fonts/Yugothib/",
    ]),

    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
        'yugoth' => [
            'R' => 'YuGothR.ttc',
            'TTCfontID' => [
                'R' => 1,
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'default_font' => 'yugoth',
    'languageToFont' => new CustomLanguageToFontImplementation()
]);

$pdf->autoScriptToLang  = true;
$pdf->autoLangToFont  = true;
$pdf->showImageErrors = true;
$pdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
        
$pdf->SetHTMLHeader();
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter();
$pdf->WriteHTML($this->getHtmlTemplate($stock, $userId, $loadedDate));

$pdf->Output($filepath, 'F');
```

And the HTML is also taken from a private function within the same class

```
function getHtmlTemplate($records, $userId, $loadedDate){
    $user = $this->getUserInfo($userId);

    $companyName = $user->client;

    $html = "
<html lang=\"ja\">
<head>
<style>
.table {
    font-family: 'yugoth', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.column-header {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #777777;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.cell{
    border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.cell-last {
    border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.a-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.w-80 {
    width: 80px;
}
.w-quality {
    width: 380px;
}
.w-150 {
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body lang=\"ja\">

<table border=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%\">
<tr>
    <td style=\"width:26%; text-align: left; font-size: 18px\">
        <div>" . $companyName ."</div><br />
        <div lang='ja'>" . pll__('Stock Info') ."</div>
    </td>
    <td class=\"a-center\" style=\"width:26%\">
        <div style=\"font-size: 50px; color: #004729; font-weight: bold;\" lang='ja'>" . pll__('Stock Report'). "</div>
    </td>
    <td style=\"width:26%; text-align: right\">
        <div>". $date ."</div><br />
        <img src=\"" . ASSETS_URL . "images/logo.png\" width=\"200px\" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class=\"table\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"7\">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class=\"column-header\" style=\"width: 100px\">" . pll__("Col 1") ."</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\" style=\"width: 100px\">" . pll__("Col 2") ."</th>
            <th class=\"column-header w-150\">" . pll__("Col 3") ."</th>
            <th class=\"column-header w-quality\">" . pll__("Col 4") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\" style=\"width: 100px\">" . pll__("Col 5") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header w-80\">" . pll__("Col 6") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\" style=\"width: 130px\">" . pll__("Col 7") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\">" . pll__("Col 8") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\">" . pll__("Col 9") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\" style=\"width: 100px\">" . pll__("Col 10") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\">" . pll__("Col 11") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header\" style=\"width: 120px\">" . pll__("Coll 12") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header w-150\">" . pll__("Col 13") . "</th>
            <th class=\"column-header w-150\">" . pll__("Col 14") . "</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
";

    /** @var StockItem $row */
    foreach ($records as $row){
        $html .= "
    <tr>
        <td class=\"cell a-center\">" . $row->col1 ."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center\">".$row->col2."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center w-150\">". $row->col3 ."</td>
        <td class=\"cell w-quality\">".$row->col4."</td>
        <td class=\"cell w-150\">".$row->col5."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center w-80\">".$row->col6."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center w-80\">".$row->col7."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center\" lang='ja'>".$row->col8."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center\">".$row->col9."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center\">".$row->col10."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center\">".$row->col11."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center w-80\">".$row->col12."</td>
        <td class=\"cell a-center w-150\">".$row->col13."</td>
        <td class=\"cell cell-last a-center w-150\">".$row->col14."</td>
    </tr>";
    }

    $html .= "
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with a proper configuration for mPDF or suggest some other configuration with other Japanese font which is already working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've changed the script to use TCPDF and this way has actually worked very nice. I know this answer did not respond to the question I've asked, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Where do you use a TCPDF? I have a problem, but I don't know how use it

Comment: I helped: `$pdf->autoScriptToLang  = true;`
and `$pdf->autoLangToFont  = true;`

Comment: I generate some PDFs with tables and some page header info, from HTML. Unfortunately, it is not the best way to manipulate tables in TCPDF. The best way is to use Cell() method, it is more accurate. Converting from HTML instead is easier and quicker